# Decentralized NLog Target per Http request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, multi-tenant, nlog

## Context

I am using NLog and .NET Web API 2 framework.

The server is a multi-tenant environment where errors are logged to individual client databases.
I have an NLog.config file that contains a DatabaseTarget but is missing (on purpose) a connection string attribute.
At the begining of a request the client's connection string is obtained and added to the database target programmatically so that errors can be logged to the client's database.

After the Web Api action has been executed, I clear the connection string so that subsequent requests don't log to the wrong database. This works just fine for consecutive requests.

## Problem

Concurrent requests to the server are all trying to change the database target's connection string at once. The means errors are logged to which ever database happened to be set on the database target last.

## Question

Is it possible to isolate an NLog instance or at the very least, logging target, to a single request?
If not, how would I achieve this?

Note: It is a requirement that the database target be configured in the NLog.config file (except it's connection string) so that it's query can be modified without changing code. I am still interested in solutions where this is not possible though eg. programmatically creating the database target.

## Code

NLog.config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <!--
      The logdatabase target's connectionString is
      added programmatically.
    -->
    <target name="logdatabase"
            xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="odbc">
      <commandText>
        <!-- super secret query is here -->
      </commandText>
      <!-- super secret parameters are here -->
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- rule is added programmatically so that there are no logging attempts before a connection string is added -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Inject connection string code snippet (called at begining of every request)

```
/// <summary>
/// Set up NLog to log to the database.
/// <param name="connectionString">Database to log to</param>
/// </summary>
private void SetUpDatabaseLogging(string connectionString)
{
    DatabaseTarget databaseTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<DatabaseTarget>("logdatabase");
    databaseTarget.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    // Add rule if it does not exist already
    if (!DatabaseRuleExists("logdatabase"))
    {
        LoggingRule logDatabase = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, databaseTarget);
        LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(logDatabase);
    }

    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}

/// <summary>
/// Check if a rule exists that uses the specified target
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool DatabaseRuleExists(string targetName)
{
    bool ruleExists = false;

    foreach (LoggingRule rule in LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules)
    {
        if (rule.Targets.Where(target => target.Name == targetName).Count() > 0)
        {
            ruleExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ruleExists;
}
```

Filter that removes connection string and logging rule (used on every controller)

```
/// <summary>
/// Clean up log database connection after request
/// </summary>
public class LogCleanUpFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

        // Remove connection string from logging target.
        DatabaseTarget databaseTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<DatabaseTarget>("logdatabase");
        databaseTarget.ConnectionString = null;

        // Remove database rule. Rule must not persist between requests
        // because we are logging to client database.
        foreach (LoggingRule rule in LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules)
        {
            if (rule.Targets.Where(target => target.Name == "logdatabase").Count() > 0)
            {
                LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Remove(rule);
                break;
            }
        }

        LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
    }
}
```

I am logging using the current class logger

```
private Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Error("I'm a naughty function");
```

Thanks guys. Sorry for the wall of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing things globally in a multi threaded environment is tricky, as you have noticed.

In this case it's better to store the connectionstring in a context that is bound to a thread. The best option is the "Mapped Diagnostic Logical Context" (`${mdlc}`), which is bound to a thread and it's async childs threads.

It also makes a lot of stuff easier, as you don't have to change the rules dynamically.

Usage:

1. Create a database target and use the MDLC for the connectionstring

   In your nlog.config:

   ```xml
   <target xsi:type="Database"
       name="target1"
       connectionString="${mdlc:myConnectionString}" .. />
   ```
2. Set the connectionstring at the beginning of your request.

   (This is all C# that is needed)

   ```
   MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("myConnectionString", "server=...user=..");
   ```

That's all. No need for `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers`, looping/changing the NLog rules.

[See docs of the MDLC](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Mdlc-Layout-Renderer)